# Make html button overlap into my game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

So I have a 3D game with a three.js perspective camera moving through a 3D space. Now when you have an item "selected" in this 3D space, I want a button to appear in the top left of the screen to unselect that item. Is there a way to do this using html? Because right now I have a button but it is pushing the game down below it instead of as a part of it which is expected from html. I think I need to make the background of the button transparent AND manually push the game up to the top of the screen.

```
<body style="background-color: #222222;">

    //Here is the button that I need to be transparent
    //because I have no way to test it, I have no idea if that style code I have makes it transparent or not
    <input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:200px;width:200px;border:0 none;background-color: transparent;"  src="media/undo.png"/>

    <script src="src/game.js"></script>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>

    //Here is where I load in the game
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //All loading stuff
        THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
        var game = new Main($(document).width() - 10, $(document).height() - 20, "res/games.json");
        game.init();
        function gameUpdate(){
            game.update();
            window.requestAnimationFrame(gameUpdate, game.renderer.domElement);
        }
        gameUpdate();
    });
    </script>
    //Done with game loading script

</body>
```

Here is a picture of the problem: http://puu.sh/dg4rJ/5a25c817b7.jpg
I need the game and button to be together. Is there anyway to do this or should I work on doing it in the game in JS?

Comment: Have you tried adding position:absolute to it?

Comment: And change the `z-index` in the CSS if necessary. The background of the image should be transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For certain you should set the background of the button to be transparent. Then what you should do is set the position of the button to be absolute. In CSS, it would look like this.

```
#myImage {
    position: absolute;
}
```

*If necessary, you would want to change the `z-index` of the image. You would do this if the button was displaying behind the game screen, and in that case you would most likely add this into your CSS:

`z-index: 1;`

Comment: So simple, I can't believe I couldn't find that through searching. Thanks!